# How to load python layer after direnv?

Tags: spacemacs, python, lsp-mode, ide, virtualenv

In order to have lsp-pyright load after pipenv I need pyright to load **after** direnv. However, appending `after: direnv` results in an error[0]

How can I have pyright starting the workspace *after* direnv? Currently I `M-x` `lsp-workspace-restart` after opening any python file (direnv loads pipenv [automatically](https://www.bassamsaeed.ca/posts/python-development-in-emacs/))

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
'(
 (python :variables
         python-backend 'lsp
         python-lsp-server 'pyright
         python-test-runner 'pytest
         python-enable-yapf-format-on-save t
         after: direnv
         )
        )
```

```
  (use-package direnv
    :demand t
    :config
    (direnv-mode)
    (setq direnv-always-show-summary nil)
    :hook
    ((prog-mode) . direnv-update-environment))
```

[0] An error occurred while setting layer variable after: (error: (void-variable direnv)). Be sure to quote the value if needed.

Comment: Are you enabling `direnv-mode` on startup Emacs?

Comment: @TianshuWang Yes, added init.el excerpt

Answer (score 0):

try to `direnv-update-environment` before `lsp-initialize`

```lisp
(use-package direnv
  :demand t
  :hook
  ((after-init . direnv-mode)
   (lsp-before-initialize-hook . direnv-update-environment))
  :config
  (setq direnv-always-show-summary nil))
```